# Input string was not in a correct format in c# net int.parse

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have string which is like this:

```
string line = "77.139305\t28.795975"
```

and i seperate the two integers like this:

```
string lat = line.Substring(0, 9);
string lng = line.Substring(10, 9);
```

whic exactly seperates the 2 numbers like this:
`"77.139305"` and `"28.795975"` for lat and lng.

```
  int latitude,longitude;
   bool result = Int32.TryParse(lat, out latitude);
                  if (result)
                  {
                      col1[i] = latitude;
                      Console.WriteLine("lat: " + col1[i]);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if (lat == null) lat = "";
                      Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of lat '{0}' failed.", lat);
                  }
                  bool result2 = Int32.TryParse(lng, out longitude);
                  if (result2)
                  {
                      col2[i] = longitude;
                      Console.WriteLine("longit: " + col2[i]);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if (lng == null) lng = "";
                      Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of lng '{0}' failed.", lng);
                  }
```

As a  result it always excutes else condition and if i don't handle this exception in else condition then it gives **"input string was not in a correct format in c# net int.parse"**
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Well, they're not integers (they have decimals), so it's not exactly surprising. Did you really want to parse to integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in floating point numbers and using an integer parsing method.

Use the [`Double.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parsing method instead.

Comment: @merling2011 thanks..i had bcme dumb bcz of headache..cudnt detect very simple thing :'(